# Are there good java gallery viewers, freely available for java (open source)

Tags: java, image

i am in need of an open source image gallery viewers for use in java? i have had a quick google around and cant find anything pure java, any suggestions would be great, any any linking stack questions would also be great!

Answer (score 1):

I've heard about this component : [Eclipse Nebula Gallery](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php), but not used it.
You may have a look if it fits your needs.